# How does 甘梅地瓜 mean sweet potato fries?

Tags: translation, food

I bought some 甘梅地瓜 (gān méi dì guā), or just 地瓜 (dì guā), and this is what I got:

[image: 甘梅地瓜]

They seem to be sweet potato fries.  I'm wondering how 甘梅地瓜 translates into "sweet potato fries"?

Google indicates that 地瓜 means "sweet potato", although I always thought that was 红薯 (hóngshǔ).  I'm not familiar with 甘梅, and Google translates it to "Gan Mei".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

甘 = sweet

梅 = plum

地瓜 = sweet potato

From the photo, "Fried Sweet Potato with sweet plum powder"

Edit: Thanks for others' correction.... 地瓜 may also mean other types of potato or other taro, depending on the region.

Comment: In southern regions of China, "甘" is the taste of Glycyrrhiza uralensis ( Chinese liquorice) and also refers to the after-taste of many herbal medicine.  Hence, "甘甜" is not simply sweet, but a combination of sweet flavours and sensation.

Answer (score 3):

Like Henry Ho explained, 甘梅地瓜 does not mean sweet potato fries.

Actually, 地瓜 may not mean sweet potato; it can be taro (山芋) too, depending on different regions.